# How to populate menu items from bean JSF

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, menu, menuitem

I am coding a dropdown menu, where a button menu is clicked and it will show it's submenus or menuitems. Currently, I am having trouble to populate the p:menuitem from the bean. Previously, I tried to code as such

```
<p:menu label="PrimeFaces" icon="ui-icon-heart">
  <p:menuitem value="Home" url="http://www.primefaces.org" icon="ui-icon-home" />
  <p:menuitem value="Docs" url="http://www.primefaces.org/documentation" icon="ui-icon-document" />
  <p:menuitem value="Download" url="http://www.primefaces.org/downloads" icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s" />
  <p:menuitem value="Support" url="http://www.primefaces.org/support" icon="ui-icon-wrench" />
</p:menu>
```

As you noticed, the menuitem values (Home, Docs, etc) are hardcoded in the JSF. How can I fetch the values from bean and populate as the menu item ? Does p:menuitem have something similar like the f:selectItems when I can set a list as the value?

What I want to try to achieve is to populate menu items from the bean and a method will be fired when the individual menu item is selected.

Help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the menu is a jsf component? I think you may be using primefaces component, The name scheme is usually defined as follows and p:menu is a component of primefaces:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" >
```

You can customize and use the menu from the bean as follows:

xhtml:

```
 <p:menu model="#{menuBean.model}" />
```

Bean:

```
public class MenuBean {

    private MenuModel model;

    public MenuBean() {

    model = new DefaultMenuModel();
    //First submenuDefaultSubMenu firstSubmenu = new DefaultSubMenu("Dynamic Submenu");
    DefaultMenuItem item = new DefaultMenuItem("External");
    item.setUrl("http://www.primefaces.org");
    item.setIcon("ui-icon-home");
    firstSubmenu.addElement(item);
    model.addElement(firstSubmenu);
    //Second submenuDefaultSubMenu secondSubmenu = new DefaultSubMenu("Dynamic Actions");
    item = new DefaultMenuItem("Save");
    item.setIcon("ui-icon-disk");
    item.setCommand("#{menuBean.save}");
    item.setUpdate("messages");
    secondSubmenu.addElement(item);
    item = new DefaultMenuItem("Delete");
    item.setIcon("ui-icon-close");
    item.setCommand("#{menuBean.delete}");
    item.setAjax(false);
    secondSubmenu.addElement(item);
    item = new DefaultMenuItem("Redirect");
    item.setIcon("ui-icon-search");
    item.setCommand("#{menuBean.redirect}");
    secondSubmenu.addElement(item);
    model.addElement(secondSubmenu);
    }

    public MenuModel getModel() { return model; }
}
```

Here you can see all the documentation:
https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_2.pdf (pag. 333)

Comment: And in the showcase ;-) And I'd say there is a duplicate of this in stackoverflow somehere ;-)

Answer (score -1):

If you use Primefaces you can try:

bean:

```
public class MyItem {
  private String value;
  private String url;
  private String icon;
  ....
  getters/setters
  ...
}


public List<MyItem> getMenuItems() {
  // build list
}
```

xhtml:

```
<p:repeat value="#{bean.menuItems}" var="item">
  <p:menuitem value="#{item.value}" url="#{item.url}" icon="#{item.icon}" />
</prepeat>
```

Comment: I tried using p:repeat but system asked to change to use ui:repeat. When I used ui:repeat, the error is shown

com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat cannot be cast to org.primefaces.model.menu.MenuElement